# how to select all date using Materializecss datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, materialize

I am using materializecss `date-picker` in my project. This is working fine for a specific date selection. But I am in need to show an option named 'All' and when I select 'All', I need to pass 'all' string to the back-end API to retrieve all the data.

In my previous project, I used bootstrap `daterangepicker`([daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#ex4)) to achieve this functionality. But I tried to achieve the same using materializes picker, no luck.

Is there any plugin available to achieve this?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <input id="date" type="date" class="datepicker">
    <label for="date">Date</label>
  </div>
</div>

$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
  selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqjy7jbb/722/)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by all?

Comment: There should be an option named 'All' and when I select 'All', I need to pass 'all' string to the back-end API